# How can i insert duplicate tag/string data into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, utf-8

Hi i am facing issue reading data from complex string.

I have to read data after string `&lt;deviMessage&gt;` and insert into table. Problem with reading data is `&lt;deviMessage&gt;` is repetitive tag and I have to read all tags `&lt;deviMessage&gt;` and insert into table.

```
<loan>&lt;applicant&gt;&lt;partyReference&gt;string&lt;/partyReference&gt;&lt;
deviations&gt;&lt;deviMessage&gt;read this data&lt;/deviMessage&gt;&lt;deviSeverity&gt;L2&lt;/deviSeverity&gt;&lt;approvalAuth&gt;CCM&lt;/approvalAuth&gt;&lt;istest&gt;NO&lt;/istest&gt;&lt;/deviations&gt;
deviations&gt;&lt;deviMessage&gt;read thid data2&lt;/deviMessage&gt;&lt;deviSeverity&gt;L2&lt;/deviSeverity&gt;&lt;approvalAuth&gt;CCM&lt;/approvalAuth&gt;&lt;istest&gt;NO&lt;/istest&gt;&lt;/deviations&gt;
&lt;Numerator&gt;0.036848584684376046&lt;/Numerator&gt;</loan>
```

Comment: What is your backend DB? Postgres, MySQL?

Comment: Microsoft sql server

Comment: anyone tried something like this?

Comment: Do you have the linebreaks exactly as above? Or did you enter them manually?

Comment: linebreaks  have entered manually to for better understanding as my result come in single row. symbols like &lt; &gt; comes with result only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XML is just one node `<loan>content</loan>`, where *content* is an embedded XML.

If you read it from the XML, it looks like this:

**Attention:** I did not correct some mistakes!

```
<applicant>
    <partyReference>string</partyReference>
    <deviations>
        <deviMessage>read this data</deviMessage>
        <deviSeverity>L2</deviSeverity>
        <approvalAuth>CCM</approvalAuth>
        <istest>NO</istest>
    </deviations>
    deviations>
        <deviMessage>read thid data2</deviMessage>
        <deviSeverity>L2</deviSeverity>
        <approvalAuth>CCM</approvalAuth>
        <istest>NO</istest>
    </deviations>
    <Numerator>0.036848584684376046</Numerator>
```

There is a `<` missing before the second `<deviations>` and the closing `</applicant>` is missing too...

If this is your real data, you are sitting in quite a mess... If you shortened this for brevity (which is a good idea), You might have cut it in an invalid way.

After repairing these errors in the input (hopefully your embedded XML is valid XML). You can do something along this:

```
DECLARE @YourXML XML='<loan>&lt;applicant&gt;&lt;partyReference&gt;string&lt;/partyReference&gt;&lt;deviations&gt;&lt;deviMessage&gt;read this data&lt;/deviMessage&gt;&lt;deviSeverity&gt;L2&lt;/deviSeverity&gt;&lt;approvalAuth&gt;CCM&lt;/approvalAuth&gt;&lt;istest&gt;NO&lt;/istest&gt;&lt;/deviations&gt;&lt;deviations&gt;&lt;deviMessage&gt;read thid data2&lt;/deviMessage&gt;&lt;deviSeverity&gt;L2&lt;/deviSeverity&gt;&lt;approvalAuth&gt;CCM&lt;/approvalAuth&gt;&lt;istest&gt;NO&lt;/istest&gt;&lt;/deviations&gt;&lt;Numerator&gt;0.036848584684376046&lt;/Numerator&gt;&lt;/applicant&gt;</loan>';

SELECT CAST(@YourXML.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS XML);
```

For this repaired XML you'd get your data by this query:

```
DECLARE @YourXML XML='<loan>&lt;applicant&gt;&lt;partyReference&gt;string&lt;/partyReference&gt;&lt;deviations&gt;&lt;deviMessage&gt;read this data&lt;/deviMessage&gt;&lt;deviSeverity&gt;L2&lt;/deviSeverity&gt;&lt;approvalAuth&gt;CCM&lt;/approvalAuth&gt;&lt;istest&gt;NO&lt;/istest&gt;&lt;/deviations&gt;&lt;deviations&gt;&lt;deviMessage&gt;read thid data2&lt;/deviMessage&gt;&lt;deviSeverity&gt;L2&lt;/deviSeverity&gt;&lt;approvalAuth&gt;CCM&lt;/approvalAuth&gt;&lt;istest&gt;NO&lt;/istest&gt;&lt;/deviations&gt;&lt;Numerator&gt;0.036848584684376046&lt;/Numerator&gt;&lt;/applicant&gt;</loan>';

SELECT TheXml.value('(/applicant/partyReference/text())[1]','nvarchar(150)') AS PartyReference
        ,devs.value('(deviMessage/text())[1]','nvarchar(150)') AS deviMessage  
        ,devs.value('(deviSeverity/text())[1]','nvarchar(150)') AS deviSeverity  
        ,devs.value('(approvalAuth/text())[1]','nvarchar(150)') AS approvalAuth  
        ,devs.value('(istest/text())[1]','nvarchar(150)') AS istest  
        ,TheXml.value('(/applicant/Numerator/text())[1]','NUMERIC') AS Numerator
FROM (SELECT CAST(@YourXML.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS XML)) AS tbl(TheXml)
CROSS APPLY TheXml.nodes('/applicant/deviations') A(devs);
```

The result

```
+----------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------+-----------+
| PartyReference | deviMessage     | deviSeverity | approvalAuth | istest | Numerator |
+----------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------+-----------+
| string         | read this data  | L2           | CCM          | NO     | 0         |
+----------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------+-----------+
| string         | read thid data2 | L2           | CCM          | NO     | 0         |
+----------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: can same result can converted into column